# Python binary search tree height function wont work

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search-tree

I've been trying the recursive approach but been stuck for too long. I cant tell if it's my BST code that's wrong or my recursion.

Regardless of how many elements I put in my tree I still get the value 2 from my height function.

```
class Treenode:
    def __init__(self, value = None, rchild = None, lchild = None):
        self.value = value
        self.rchild = rchild
        self.lchild = lchild

class bin_tree:
   def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

   def put(self, x):
       if self.root is None:
           self.root = Treenode(x)
           return True
       if self.exists(x) == True:
           return False

       p = self.root

       while True:
           if x < p.value:
              if p.lchild is None:
                 p.lchild = Treenode(x)
                 return True
               else:
                   p = p.lchild
           elif x > p.value:
               if p.rchild is None:
                  p.rchild = Treenode(x)
                  return True
               else:
                  p = p.rchild
                  return

   def exists(self, x):
      p = self.root
         while True and p != None:
            if p.value == x:
               return True
            elif p.value > x and p.lchild != None:
               p = p.lchild
            elif p.value < x and p.rchild != None:
               p = p.rchild
            else:
               return False

   def isempty(self):
      return self.root == None

   def height(self):
      def gh(enrot):
         if enrot == None:
            return 0
         else:
            return 1 + max(gh(enrot.lchild), gh(enrot.rchild))
      return gh(self.root)
```

Example code:

```
from Bintree import *

p = bin_tree()

x = input()

for word in x.split():
    p.put(word)

a = input()

if p.exists(a) is True:
    print('Exists!')
else:
    print('Does not exist!')

print(p.isempty())

print(p.height())
```

Comment: Could you give us a sample tree for which this gives the wrong answer?

Comment: It looks like you have mixed tabs and spaces. While it's not clear whether this is causing your current problem, it will cause problems eventually, and you will be so damn confused why your code with no visible bugs is producing errors.

Comment: If I call the put() function for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 seperatly for example, same goes for strings. Still get 2. I do get 0 if I use it on an empty tree though.

Comment: What is  `p = p.rchild` in the else supposed to do? You just return but never use it.

Comment: I had some problems pasting it here on stack, I dont get any errors at all from the code. It's just that my height function wont return anything apart from 2 or 0.

Comment: Also add a runnable example that recreates the issue

Comment: the p = p.rchild is from my understanding used to restart the while loop with a new node to look at.

Comment: @MarcusLindström, that ends the loop so you do nothing with p

Comment: Just remove the return so the loop does not end prematurely, on a sidenote use `is None` and `is not None` not `==` and camel case you class names `BinTree`

Comment: Thanks so much, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The `height` method is fine. In your `put` method, you stop without actually adding the element, so the height doesn't actually grow beyond 2:

```
   def put(self, x):
       ...
       while True:
           if x < p.value:
              ...
           elif x > p.value:
               if p.rchild is None:
                  ...
               else:
                  p = p.rchild
                  return
#                 ^^^^^^ This shouldn't be here.
```

Comment: So the return gets me back in the 'While True:' loop? I tried it, still get 2 :/

Comment: @MarcusLindström: No, the return gets you out of the function entirely. What do you think return does?

Comment: that's actually what I thought, I guess I dont understand your code. Why did you put a return at the end?

Comment: @MarcusLindström: I didn't put it there. **You did.**

Comment: Haha sry. I looked at a different part of the code. Now it works! Thanks so much!